# How do I change iframe attributes based on checkbox inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

First, I'm sorry in advance my code is so terrible. Total novice here.

For fun, I'm putting together a basic website that lets you view another website in a [sandboxed iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp). What I have so far has been hastily hashed together from code I've found on the internet and my own incredibly basic knowledge of html. What I'm stuck at though is how to implement the sandbox feature.

What I'm looking for is for the checkboxes that I've included on my site to turn on and off the sandbox overrides. I don't know enough java script to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Bubble Wrap
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function wrapWebsiteInBubble(){
            var browserFrame = document.getElementById("bubble");
            browserFrame.src= document.getElementById("wrap").value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:sans-serif;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="allow-forms" value="allow-forms"> Allow forms
    <input type="checkbox" id="allow-pointer-lock" value="allow-pointer-lock"> Allow pointer lock
    <input type="checkbox" id="allow-popups" value="allow-popups"> Allow popups
    <input type="checkbox" id="allow-same-origin" value="allow-same-origin"> Allow same origin
    <input type="checkbox" id="allow-scripts" value="allow-scripts"> Allow scripts
    <input type="checkbox" id="allow-top-navigaton" value="allow-top-navigation"> Allow top navigation
    <br>
    <form method="post" target="bubble">
        <input type="text" id="wrap" style="width:88%;" placeholder="https://www.example.com" name="url"/>
        <input style="width:8%;" type="button" value="Wrap" onclick="wrapWebsiteInBubble(); return false;"/>
    </form>
    <iframe id="bubble" name="bubble" src="http://google.com" style="height:100%; width:100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S.
Is there anything I should definitely do to make my code better?

Comment: _P.S. Is there anything I should definitely do to make my code better?_ Please see my updated answer with explanations of what I have changed and for what reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bubble Wrap</title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function wrapWebsiteInBubble() {
            var browserFrame = document.getElementById("bubble");
            browserFrame.src = document.getElementsByName("url")[0].value;

            // get which checkboxes are checked
            var sandbox = "";

            if (document.getElementById("allow-forms").checked) {
                sandbox += "allow-forms ";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("allow-pointer-lock").checked) {
                sandbox += "allow-pointer-lock ";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("allow-popups").checked) {
                sandbox += "allow-popups ";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("allow-same-origin").checked) {
                sandbox += "allow-same-origin ";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("allow-scripts").checked) {
                sandbox += "allow-scripts ";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("allow-top-navigaton").checked) {
                sandbox += "allow-top-navigaton ";
            }

            browserFrame.sandbox = sandbox;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: sans-serif;">
    <form id="myForm" method="post" target="bubble">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sandbox" id="allow-forms" value="allow-forms" /> Allow forms</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sandbox" id="allow-pointer-lock" value="allow-pointer-lock" /> Allow pointer lock</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sandbox" id="allow-popups" value="allow-popups" /> Allow popups</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sandbox" id="allow-same-origin" value="allow-same-origin" /> Allow same origin</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sandbox" id="allow-scripts" value="allow-scripts" /> Allow scripts</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sandbox" id="allow-top-navigaton" value="allow-top-navigation" /> Allow top navigation</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="wrap" style="width: 88%;" placeholder="https://www.example.com" name="url" />
        <input style="width: 8%;" type="button" value="Wrap" onclick="wrapWebsiteInBubble(); return false;" />
    </form>
    <iframe id="bubble" name="bubble" src="" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a list of changes:

- Put `<title>` on the same line.
- Fixed that `src` attribute was trying to access the submit button and not the input.
- I also removed the IDs from the inputs and instead changed them to have a name attribute.
- Wrapped inputs in a label tag which means that you can click on the name next to each checkbox to select it rather than having to click the little box. That is just better user experience (UX) in my opinion.
- Connected the checkboxes and added them to `browserFrame`
  This involved accessing the IDs that you had set for each of the inputs. I then checked to see if they had been ticked (that is what the `checked` property is), if true it would add them into a string.
  **Note:** that I didn't do a `=== true` check on the if statement as the checked property returns a boolean value anyway.

Ideally, it would be better to not set IDs for each of the inputs. Instead, it would have been better to access the name and then select all the inputs with the type of checkbox and iterate over those.

```js
function wrapWebsiteInBubble() {
    var browserFrame = document.getElementById("bubble");
    browserFrame.src = document.getElementsByName("url")[0].value;

    // get which checkboxes are checked
    var sandbox = "";
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("sandbox");

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox" && checkboxes[i].checked) {
            sandbox += checkboxes[i].value + " ";
        }
    }

    browserFrame.sandbox = sandbox;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a function to a click event on your checkbox. In this function you should get the value of the check box and add/remove the string from the iframe's sandbox attribute.

```
window.onload = function(){
  // Grab elements
  var iframe = document.getElementById('bubbles');
  var input = document.getElementById('allow-forms');

  // Add click event
  input.addEventListener('click', toggleForms);

  function toggleForms() {
      // Get value of checkbox
      var value = input.checked;
      var sandboxAttr = iframe.getAttribute('sandbox');

      if(value) {
         // Add 'allow-forms'   
      } else {
         // Remove 'allow-forms'
      }
   }
}
```

P.S. You'll probably want to wrap the javascript code in a `window.onload` function to be sure that the DOM has loaded before your JS runs. Or you can have the script tag after the closing `<body>` tag.

Comment: This doesn’t add all the other checkboxes into the attribute...? It only adds `allow-forms` and even then you don’t show the code to do so. This is someone who has no experience and this solution just seems overkill.

Comment: That was intentional. I didn't realize your skill level and assumed that you wanted help to figure out what direction to go in. I don't have time to write out all of your code for you. This was meant as an example of the logic I would use. There's plenty of sources for figuring out JS syntax. I prefer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Or you could check out [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) which is great for beginners.

Comment: I’m not OP... I was simply ong saying that you didn’t really “answer” the question per se. You didn’t specify that this would only add one input. It’s fine to be somewhat vague; just make it clear in your answer where you are being vague and where the OP should go next. The OP stated in his first sentence “total novice here” which was the indication of his lacklustre skill set.